# Getting text value from React Element child in enzyme

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have the following component as part of my large component.

```
<UI.Field
   horizontal
     value={
       <FormattedNumber
         style="currency"
         currency="EUR"
         data-service-fee
         value={booking.service_fee_cents || 8000 / 100}
       />
       }
      label={`${base}service_fee`}
      />
```

I'm writing tests for the component.

```
it('renders default value if service fee is null', () => {
      wrapper.setProps({
        booking: {
          ...make(booking),
          service_fee_cents: null,
        },
      })
      expect(wrapper.find('[data-service-fee]').text()).toBe('€80.00')
    })
```

What I'm trying to do is to get the value inside the field named `data-service-fee`. But `wrapper.find('[data-service-fee]')` always return null.

When I tried `wrapper.find('[label*="service_fee"]').text()` it return the component itself instead of text ?

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the prop of a component using `prop` method on the ShallowWrapper.

**Any DOM element attribute could also be retrieved using `prop`.**

wrapper.prop('data-service-fee') should give you the value.

Reference - [ShallowWrapper.prop()](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/prop.html)

Comment: This always returns `undefined` for me :/ Since its a shallow render and its a nested element, its not being rendered I think.

Comment: Feels like a hacky solution but this solves the issue:

`const elemProps: any = wrapper.find('[label*="service_fee"]').props()
      const elemValues: any = elemProps.value.props.value
      expect(elemValues).toBe(80)`

Comment: If you're trying to access a nested element you should use `mount` instead of `shallow`.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to avoid use of `mount` for different reasons.

Comment: Ideal way to shallow test any component would be only test the component's first level. But in your case, you want to make sure the child component receives the right prop. This has worked for me sometimes in ShallowWrapper. wrapper.find('ChildComponent').prop('prop-name')